# Posicionar conteudo dentro do Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando e remodelando um navbar cujo template é feito pelo próprio site do Bootstrap porem após fazer inserções das classes que julgava capaz de posicionar os objetos notei que eles não estavam funcionando (apesar de muitos estarem), então aqui esta um print da pagina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o meu intuito era centralizar o formulario search (inclui os radio button) e colocar no mesmo nivel os botões login e create account

Codigo com Bootstrap:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="">Option 1</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><button class="btn btn-default">Login</a></li>
                    <li><button class="btn btn-default">Create Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que isso irá te ajudar:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
```

Substitua o código antigo pelo código acima.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Nos botões Login e Create Account use a classe navbar-btn. Estou vendo o problema do campo de texto da pesquisa e já te dou outra resposta.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Adicione este código nos botões: <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Login</button> <button class="btn btn-default">Create Account</button>